# Sum column with alias name?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to sum a column that has an alias name (since to create the column I had to do math on other columns). I know that you can't do this (aggregate functions on aliases created within the same select query) but none of the solutions I have searched seem to work for me.

This my code

```
Select 
o.Order_Value Total_Price_Before_Discount, 
od.Price*od.Quantity_Ordered as Line_Price_Before_Discount, 
od.Discount_Value, od.Discount_Percentage, 
od.Price*od.Quantity_Ordered-od.Discount_Value as Line_Price_After_Discount,

sum(Line_Price_After_Discount) as Total_Price_After_Discount, -- this is the problem line

from Orders o (nolock)
join Order_Detail od (nolock) on 
o.Company_Code=od.Company_Code and o.Division_Code=od.Division_Code
```

I tried

```
sum(od.Price*od.Quantity_Ordered-od.Discount_Value) as Total_Price_After_Discount
```

but that didn't work and I get a group by error

```
 invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Which I don't fully understand.

Comment: You have to repeat the expression or use a subquery (or CTE in MySQL 8+).  Your code is not MySQL code, however.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. I should have tagged the correct database now. Can you explain what you mean by repeating the expression or using a subquery?

Comment: you are missing a Group By if you are going to Use the `SUM` function.

Comment: By "repeating the expression" he meant what you tried in the second code block of your question; the comment above me addresses why your query still failed after making that change. You must GROUP BY every non-aggregated field referenced in the SELECT list.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep existing values with sum you need to use `OVER` clause with `PARTITION BY`. If you change your script with following it should work.

Also, are you sure your join is correct? Company_Code and Division_Code are odd to join Order and Order_Detail tables.

```
Select 
    o.Order_Value Total_Price_Before_Discount, 
    od.Price*od.Quantity_Ordered as Line_Price_Before_Discount, 
    od.Discount_Value, od.Discount_Percentage, 
    od.Price*od.Quantity_Ordered-od.Discount_Value as Line_Price_After_Discount,

    --sum(Line_Price_After_Discount) as Total_Price_After_Discount, -- this is the problem line
    SUM(od.Price*od.Quantity_Ordered-od.Discount_Value) OVER(PARTITION BY o.Company_Code,o.Division_Code) AS Total_Price_After_Discount

from Orders o (nolock)
join Order_Detail od (nolock) on o.Company_Code=od.Company_Code and o.Division_Code=od.Division_Code
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix is to wrap your query in a CTE or sub-query, and then move the aggregation outside of it

```
select 
    *,
    sum(Line_Price_After_Discount) as Total_Price_After_Discount
from(
    Select 
       o.Order_Value Total_Price_Before_Discount, 
       od.Price*od.Quantity_Ordered as Line_Price_Before_Discount, 
       od.Discount_Value, 
       od.Discount_Percentage, 
       od.Price*od.Quantity_Ordered-od.Discount_Value as Line_Price_After_Discount
    from Orders o (nolock)
    join Order_Detail od (nolock) on 
    o.Company_Code=od.Company_Code and o.Division_Code=od.Division_Code
    ) x
group by 
    Total_Price_Before_Discount,
    Line_Price_Before_Discount,
    Discount_Value,
    Discount_Percentage,
    Line_Price_After_Discount
```

Comment: I believe you missed to add GROUP BY.

Comment: Yup @ZekiGumus added that in